# jQuery parseJSON help for SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON value like this:

```
{"223":[{"virtuemart_state_id":"1","state_name":"Alabama"},{"virtuemart_state_id":"2","state_name":"Alaska"}]}
```

& I am trying to parsing data like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        var state,
        url = 'http://localhost/jquery/test.json';

      $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.223, function(i, rep){
            state += "<option value = '" + rep.virtuemart_state_id + "'>" + rep.state_name + "</option>";

        });
        $("#state").html(state);
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<div id="result">
    <select id="state">
    </select>
</div>
```

But it's not working with the number 223 & I am getting error like this: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`
Any idea in where I made mistake ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `$.each(data[223]` . You can't refer object property with .

Answer (score 1):

`data.223` is not valid Javascript. It'd have to be `data['223']`. The `.` shortcut notation is handy, but it can't handle all the possible key-names you actually create in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to an object property whose name isn't a valid identifier using the `.` operator. Instead, you'd do this:

```
    $.each(data[223], function(i, rep){
```